# C#: Multiple class instances all doing the same thing

Tags: c#, .net, oop, object, instance

I have 3 different classes:  Entity, Control and Environment

Inside the Entity class, I have a Control variable:

`readonly Control m_Control`

Inside the constructor of my Entity class, I'm instantiating the Control  class. There is an Update method in the Entity class which checks the status of an enum in the Control class:

```
public class Entity
{

   public float Rotate {get; private set;}

   readonly Control m_Control

   public Entity(float rot)
   {
     Rotate = rot;
     m_control = new Control();
   }

    public void Update(float time)
    {

            switch (m_control.Rotating())
            {
                case Control.Rotator.Right:
                    Rotate += time * 1.5f;
                    break;
                case Control.Rotator.Left:
                    Rotate -= time * 1.5f;
                    break;
                case Control.Rotator.Still:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;          
            }
     }



}
```

Control class:

```
public class Control
{
        private Random rnd = new Random();
        private int _randomTurn;

        public enum Rotator
        {
            Still,
            Right,
            Left
        }

        public Control()
        {
            TimerSetup(); // Initialize timer for Entity
        }

 public Rotator Rotating()
        {

                switch(_randomTurn)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return Rotator.Right;
                    case 2:
                        return Rotator.Left;
                    default:
                        return Rotator.Still;
                }

            }

 private void TimerSetup()
 {
            DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(GameTickTimer_Tick);
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
 }


 private void GameTickTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     RandomTurn();
 }


 private void RandomTurn() 
 {
    _randomTurn = rnd.Next(1, 4);
 }


}
```

The `Environment` class is where I'm instantiating each Entity. So I would have 2 instances of `Entity`.

```
public class Environment
{

readonly Entity m_entity;
readonly Entity m_entity2;

public Environment()
{
   m_entity = new Entity(90.0f);
   m_entity2 = new Entity(180.0f);
}


 public void Update(float time)
        {
            m_entity.Update(time);

            m_entity2.Update(time);
        }
}
```

My problem is that when I instantiate multiple Entities, each of these Entities all do the exact same thing.

For example, the Control class has a rotation function, but each instantiated Entity moves in the exact same way at the exact same time.

What would be the best way for me to go about this so that each instantiated Entity acts independently?

Comment: We're missing some code here. Please provide a complete minimal version (you show a constructor for `Entity` with no parameters, then call one with 3. There is no code of the `Control` class and no code actually trying to change an `Entity`)

Comment: I think your Entity class fields is **Static** so all two instantiate do last signs

Comment: Hi, I have now provided more of the code for each of the classes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem you're facing is something that is hard to see.

The problem lies in the way the `Random` class is instantiated. Random generators start with a seed value and that seed value determines all the numbers that are returned by that generator. So 2 instances of a random generator with the same seed values will generate the same sequence of numbers. Now if you don't provide a seed value when you create a random generator it'll create a seed value itself from the system clock. However if you create 2 random generators right after each other the system clock will not have changed yet and they'll receive the same seed and therefor produce the same sequence.

So it's always important to insure you're not creating multiple `Random` instances at the same time.

If you change the `rnd` property in your `Control` class like this:

```
private static Random rnd = new Random();
```

It should work. The static makes sure that this property is shared by all instances of your `Control` class (so only one instance of `Random` is created).

Hope this helps and good luck with your project!

Comment: That did the trick :)  Thanks so much for the help and explanation!